# Android Braintree, Paypal not working, Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class

Tags: android, paypal-sandbox, braintree

Receiving this error

```
Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class 
java.lang.Class<com.braintreepayments.api.BraintreeFragment$15>: 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: 
Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient$ConnectionCallbacks;
```

I'm using Kotlin btw, if that's helpful information.

Steps to replicate

1. Call this method

   ```
   fun onBraintreeSubmit() { 
       val dropInRequest = DropInRequest().clientToken(clientToken) 
       startActivityForResult(dropInRequest.getIntent(this), REQUEST_CODE_PAY) 
   }
   ```
2. Select Paypal
3. Tap Proceed with Sandbox Purchase, I followed the setup links [here](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/drop-in/setup-and-integration/android/v2)

   On my app level `build.gradle` I have

   ```
   compile 'com.braintreepayments.api:braintree:2.9.0'
   compile 'com.braintreepayments.api:drop-in:3.+'
   ```

On the `MainActivity`

In oncreate I do

```
braintreeFragment = BraintreeFragment.newInstance(this@MainActivity, clientToken) 
braintreeFragment.addListener(this@MainActivity)
```

I also have a click listener that initializes a DropIn

```
val dropInRequest = DropInRequest() .clientToken(clientToken) 
startActivityForResult(dropInRequest.getIntent(this), REQUEST_CODE_PAY)
```

Where the `clientToken` is the sample token from the docs

```
eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIj...ib2ZmIn0=
```

I also saw issue [#109](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_android/issues/109) so I tried doing a compile

```
'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
```

But it seems to break my project.

Just want to understand what's causing the error

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error, there seems to be several possible causes but in my case, I was missing the following code in the manifest:

```
<activity android:name="com.braintreepayments.api.BraintreeBrowserSwitchActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="${applicationId}.braintree" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

As specified [here](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/client-sdk/setup/android/v2)